# Function which returns a list when the condition is satisfied; Python

Tags: python, database, function, if-statement

*Problem:*
1) Imported data set called dataset1. This data set has, in excel speak, 5-10 columns of data, with variable names var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d, var_e etc. var_a has names, var_d has numbers.
2) Task is to create a function of x that pulls all entries from var_a when var_d is equal to 2.
3) The function is then tested by calling on myfunction(dataset1)

*Attempted solution*:
Having read up on this, I opted for the following method, which, unfortunately, brings about a syntax error...

> def myfunction(x):
>       return item['var_a'] for item in x if item['var_d'] == 2

Could anyone please point me in the right direction to solve this?

I have also tried to point towards item[x['var_a']] and same for var_d, but it still shows a syntax error.

Grateful for any ideas.

Comment: you forgot the square brackets in your list comprehension: `return [item['var_a'] for item in x if item['var_d'] == 2]`

Comment: Thank you! I no longer get the syntax error :) However, now I have a new problem: when I try to execute the function myfunction(dataset1) i get TypeError: string indices must be integers